# Grails + Mongodb + Spock: NullPointerException being thrown when doing embedded field query

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-2.0, spock

On one service I'm trying to do something like:

```
Organization.withCriteria {
            eq( "active", true )
            eq( "location.region", region)
        }
```

***which is working*** but when calling the method inside a unit test I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.keyvalue.mapping.config.KeyValuePersistentEntity.getPropertyByName(KeyValuePersistentEntity.java:75)
    at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.validatePropertyName(CriteriaBuilder.java:954)
    at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.eq(CriteriaBuilder.java:435)
    at com.apposit.terra.connect.service.OrganizationService.getAllOrganizationsInZone_closure9(OrganizationService.groovy:322)
    at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.invokeClosureNode(CriteriaBuilder.java:980)
    at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(CriteriaBuilder.java:314)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withCriteria_closure11(GormStaticApi.groovy:305)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:37)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withCriteria(GormStaticApi.groovy:304)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
Organization.withCriteria {
        eq( "active", true )
        location {
           eq( "region", region)
        }

    }
```

If not please file a JIRA at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB

Comment: Graeme, thanks for mentioning this. I tried it and it worked. I thought this gave me "no join allowed on mongo" in the past when I tried on the same embedded field. But why is my method not working only on the unit test?