# Grails using Mongodb : Spock Exception thrown when using withCriteria

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, spock

In one of my service, I'm trying to do something like:

```
User.withCriteria {
    eq( "location.city", city)
}
```

it throws the following **NullPointerException** 
It is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601219/grails-mongodb-spock-nullpointerexception-being-thrown-when-doing-embedded#)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.keyvalue.mapping.config.KeyValuePersistentEntity.getPropertyByName(KeyValuePersistentEntity.java:75)
    at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.validatePropertyName(CriteriaBuilder.java:954)
    at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.eq(CriteriaBuilder.java:435)
    at com.apposit.terra.connect.service.OrganizationService.getAllOrganizationsInZone_closure9(OrganizationService.groovy:322)
    at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.invokeClosureNode(CriteriaBuilder.java:980)
    at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(CriteriaBuilder.java:314)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withCriteria_closure11(GormStaticApi.groovy:305)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:37)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withCriteria(GormStaticApi.groovy:304)
```

when I use this like suggested in the answer:

```
User.withCriteria {
    location { 
        eq( "city", city)
    }
}
```

This new **NullPointerException** is thrown.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.resolvePropertyValue(Query.java:268)    
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.addToJunction(Query.java:636)   
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.add(Query.java:141)     
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.add(Query.java:131)     
at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.addToCriteria(CriteriaBuilder.java:1141)     
at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.eq(CriteriaBuilder.java:459)
```

what should I use ?

Answer (score 1):

The criteria-support is not fully implemented for mongo-plugin, and this is good, because you should use the native mongo queries to do the sub-documents lookup and many more.

This is how it's done in your case:

```
User.collection.find( [ 'location.city':city ] ).list()
```